# Function parameters, list and int in python

Tags: python, function

i'm trying to write a function that takes a list and a int as its arguments.

```
functionName(*args, number)
   #do stuff
```

number needs to be an int but i keep getting a syntax error in IDLE (that's the IDE i'm using)

Comment: Two andies? Who's the *real* one? ;)

Answer (score 3):

If your first argument is to be a list, remove the `*`:

```
def functionName(listob, number):
```

The `*args` syntax is used to catch an *arbitrary number of positional arguments* and must be listed *after* all other positional (and keyword) arguments:

```
def functionName(number, *args):
```

because it allows your function to be called with *just* the number, or with any number of extra arguments; `functionName(42, 'foo', 'bar')` results in `number = 42` and `args = ('foo', 'bar')`. That's not the same as passing in a list object however.

Python doesn't otherwise constrain the types of objects that can be passed in; `*args` would present extra arguments to your function as a tuple, but only because that's the best way to represent 0 or more arguments extra passed into your function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `*args` before an actual argument. So you can call it like this:

```
def foo(name, *args)
```

However, you want a list, so there's no need for `*args`. Having the following signature will do just fine:

```
def foo(name, lst)
```